# Не работает добавление CHECK в таблицу. MySQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных, запрос

Необходимо создать ограничение целостности, контролирующее, чтобы вес товара не превышал 500 кг. Я пишу:

```js
ALTER TABLE Goods ADD CHECK (weight <= 500);
UPDATE `Goods` SET `weight` = '502' WHERE `Goods`.`id` = 12;
```

Выводит следующую ошибку:
[image: Выводимая ошибка]

При этом оба запроса проходят нормально, прост не создаётся никаких ограничений. Задачу по условию нельзя решать через триггеры.

Comment: Какая **точная** версия MySQL?

Comment: @Akina 
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.1.0

Comment: Да кому нужна версия клиента?

Comment: @Akina ой, если речь про версию MySQL-сервера, то вот **5.7.26-0ubuntu0.16.04.1** выдаёт запрос.

Comment: :facepalm: [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  CREATE TABLE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) *The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.*

Comment: @Akina о, дошло, спасибо